Would a diode more ideal than Shockley diode equation violate the second law of thermodynamics?
The Shockley diode equation describes the behavior of all diodes extremely well. Semiconductor p-n diodes and Schottky diodes are described by the very same equation. Furthermore, it applies to light emitting diodes and solar panels as well.
The Shockley diode equation is:
$$ I = I_s \cdot \left(\exp\left(\frac{V}{n\cdot V_t}\right)-1\right) $$
Where $I$ is the current through the diode, $I_s$ is the reverse saturation current (varies by many orders of magnitude between diodes depending on their typical forward voltage drop), $V$ the voltage across the diode, $n$ is the nonideality factor, for perfectly ideal diodes 1 but for nonideal diodes may even be 2 and $V_t = \frac{k_B \cdot T}{q_e}$ is the thermal voltage where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $T$ is the temperature and $q_e$ is the elementary charge.
I know that it's possible to build slowly acting active diodes more ideal than the Shockley diode equation says. For example, put a diode somewhere and then a MOSFET across it (with its body diode in the same direction) and close the MOSFET switch when detecting voltage in the correct direction, and open the MOSFET switch when not detecting the voltage in the correct direction anymore. However, these active diodes are slow and can pass too much current in the incorrect direction for a short time.
Let us suppose that I have access to a diode that's more ideal than the Shockley diode equation, and acts instantly. For the purposes of this question, we can assume that "more ideal" means that it obeys the Shockley diode equation with $n < 1$.
Can I build a machine that violates the second law of thermodynamics with such a more-ideal-than-Shockley diode? If I put two of these diodes at different temperatures, could I extract more work from the temperature difference than Carnot's efficiency says?
At least I know that a perfect ratchet could allow extracting heat from the random motion of a gas. However, Feynmann showed that such a perfect ratchet cannot exist and that all real ratchets allow randomly backwards motion, and extracting heat from the random motion of a gas with a ratchet is equivalent to a heat engine with two reservoirs at different temperatures, and obeys Carnot efficiency.

About the reverse current when making an "ideal diode" with a MOSFET, PN junctions also conduct in reverse briefly after being switched from forward bias --- google "diode reverse recovery time".

You should explain why you think that one could  "extract work " from two diodes at different temperatures. In particular, why this should be possible with an ideality factor smaller than 1.

Two reasons. Firstly, because an ideal ratchet can already violate thermodynamics like Feynmann showed and diode is kind of a ratchet, and secondly, because I'm not aware of any real diode that would be better than Shockley diode equation, which makes me think the could be a fundamental law of nature that a better diode is impossible.
